# Django queryset to pandas (from_records()) time optimization for bulk data?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, postgresql, django-queryset, bulk-load

I'm using django with pandas dataframe to handling bulk data like 17000 records from postgresql database. Django queryset fetch the data less than .5 seconds.

But if i used dataframe to read like 
`df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(queryset).fillna(0).`
It takes more than 27 seconds. Code sample which i used is,

```
queryset = InputFile.objects.filter(
        Q(date_time__range=(start_date, end_date)) & Q(id=str(id)) 
        & ~Q(col1=str(val_1)) & ~Q(col1=str(val_2))
        & ~Q(col2=str(val_2)) & ~Q(col3=str(val_2)) 
        & ~Q(col4=str(val_1)) & ~Q(col2=str(val_2)) 
        & ~Q(col5=str(val_2))  & ~Q(col6=str(val_2)) 
        & ~Q(col3=str(val_2)) & ~Q(col3=str(val_3)) 
        & ~Q(col6=str(val_2)) & ~Q(col5=str(val_3))).order_by('input_file_id').distinct().values(
                'col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6', 'col7', 'col8', 'col9')

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(queryset).fillna(0)
```

Is there any way to optimise above code using pandas with django queryset.